# Change Styling of jQuery Dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing a mobile application using HTML5, CSS3, jQuery (jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css). IN one section of the application I have a dropdown menu from where the user selects a particular value.

```
<div style="margin-top:08%">
    <select id="dispMOD" onchange="getID(selectedIndex)" style="display: block;margin-left: 10%;margin-right: 10%;">
        <option>Select Recipient</option>
    </select>
    <textarea id="remarksBox" placeholder="Enter Remarks here..." rows="6" style="border: 1px solid; margin-top:04%; text-align:left;width:75%;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;"></textarea>
    <button class="button icon-right ion-paper-airplane button-small button-dark" onclick="submit()" id="submit"style="margin: 0 auto;width:40%;">Send</button></div>
```

Now I want to change the styling (Height, width, text)of the dropdown (select tag) from jQuery.css file but I am not able to find which is the corresponding element to be changed. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I am developing the application for Android devices with version 4.0 or greater

Comment: When you disable the native style, then you can change the way the select and options are displayed.

Answer (score -1):

When using jQuery mobile the default option for displaying the select/options depends on the platform you are viewing the page in. The above code will show *regular* select options in desktop, apple style select in iOS and Android style in Android devices

To change this you have to first use the custom select that jQuery mobile provides. They will convert select and options into divs and other HTML elements

Then you can overwrite the style of these elements easily.

To use the custom display set the data attribute `data-native-menu="false"` of the select tag

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/06h8u5La/

```
<select id="dispMOD" onchange="getID(selectedIndex)" style="display: block;margin-left: 10%;margin-right: 10%;" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Select Recipient</option>
</select>
```

[image]

**EDIT**

> I checked the fiddle however, I am not able to edit the styling for
>   the dropdown. For ex. in the above sample, the  is stretching
>   across the page; I am not able to decide how much should be the width
>   of . Adding margin did not help as you can see. –  user3932624
>   3 mins ago

The *select* class is `ui-select` and the options are in a hidden `div` that will show up when *select* is clicked the class of the `div` is `ui-selectmenu`

Use your browser inspection tools to find out what the element is.

Comment: I checked the fiddle however, I am not able to edit the styling for the dropdown. For ex. in the above sample, the <select> is stretching across the page; I am not able to decide how much should be the width of <select>. Adding margin did not help as you can see.

Comment: yes, because the select is replaced with `div`s. you should inspect and edit the style of these elements